# How to get a nth git log in a branch

Tags: git

git log -1 shows last commit and git log -2 shows last two commit ;
How can get log for a single commit in history.

```
    commit 1
    commit 2
    commit 3
    commit 4
```

How to get just one commit in history so that I can see just commit 3, how to get lets say just

```
     commit 3
```

if I know the hash then I can use git show  to retrieve it how can we  get last nth commit without knowing the hash.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [specify a revision](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) in the past using the `~` suffix:

```
git show HEAD~4
git log -1 HEAD~4
```

will show the 4th-last commit starting from HEAD.

Another way of specifying the same revision is `HEAD^^^^`

Comment: I'm came across this answer because I want to find the 899th commt. I think I gonna stick with the `HEAD^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...` solution 

Comment: `HEAD~n` doesn't work as expected if there are merge commits. @Marco's solution with `git show -1 --skip=n` is better.

Comment: @CoDEmanX: well, depends on what you consider a commit. Although I'm not entirely sure on the differences between the two commands. Can you give an example?

Comment: I want to show the changes made in the *n*th commit, based on the position as seen in `git log`. Assume you are on branch master and made an `initial commit`. Now create a new branch `foo`, do a change and commit, checkout branch `master`, do a conflicting change and commit, then merge branch `foo` with `--strategy-option theirs`. The log will be like: merge branch `foo`, commit in `master` branch, commit in `foo` branch, initial commit. Now try to show the commits: `git show HEAD` will give you merge branch `foo`, `git show HEAD~1` commit in `master`, but `git show HEAD~2` **initial commit**!

Comment: @CoDEmanX: well, yes. `initial commit` **is** the second parent on master. `~2` means: »the second first-parent«. But again, it all depends on what you expect to be counted. `git log` can receive additional arguments to order commits in a different order (e.g. `--date-order`); not sure how that affects the behavior of `--skip`. `HEAD~2` is always going to be deterministic

Answer (score 10):

```
git log -1 --skip=n
```

will skip the first n-commits, and just show 1 commit

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but since I came here from Google, and my question ("How to get a nth git log in a branch", but *the way I understand it*) was not answered here, here's how to find the nth commit *if you don't count backwards*:

```
git log -n 1 --skip $(expr $(git log --oneline | wc -l) - 1) # show the 1st commit
git log -n 1 --skip $(expr $(git log --oneline | wc -l) - 100) # show the 100th commit
```

I think you get the point.

Comment: You can add this as a bash alias using `alias <name>='f(){ git log -n 1 --skip $(expr $(git log --oneline | wc -l) - "$@"); unset -f f; }; f'` and then call with `<name> <number>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git show` with a relative reference which walks the parents of `head`:

```
git show head~2
```